# I am having trouble solving this Integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$\int\frac{3x^3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+4}}dx$

I have tried doing it by the substitution method but after finding the derivative of $\sqrt[3]{x^4+4}$, I am at a loss as to what I should do next.

```
      Please help me solve it step by step. Thank you very much!
```

Comment: Actually, u = $x^4 + 4$

Comment: substitute $u=x^4+4$. you'll have $\frac{3x^3}{\sqrt[3]{u}}$. next find $\frac{du}{dx}$ and get $dx$ then from there you have everything to integrate easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeting $u=x^4+4$, we have $du=4x^3dx$, and

\begin{eqnarray}
\int\frac{3x^3}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+4}}dx&=&\frac{3}{4}\int\frac{4x^3dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^4+4}}\\
dx&=&\frac{3}{4}\int\frac{du}{\sqrt[3]{u}}=\frac{3}{4}\int u^{-1/3}du\\
&=&\frac{3}{4}\frac{u^{2/3}}{2/3}+C=\frac{9}{8}\sqrt[3]{u^2}+C\\
&=&\frac{9}{8}\sqrt[3]{(x^4+4)^2}+C
\end{eqnarray}